# Why This String Not Changed to Uppercase

Tags: python, string, methods

I write some code

i don't know why my string doesn't changed

although i'm use upper method

```
def Input():
        a = input('Type Anything\n')
        print('\n')
        a.upper()
        print(a)
Input()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a.upper() returns a string in Upper case. So you will have to assign this back to the variable a.

```
def Input():
    a = input('Type Anything\n')
    print('\n')
    a = a.upper()
    print(a)
Input()
```